# How to get rid of layer that appears on top of navigation bar when list comes under navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to set navigation view be always black, even when list comes under it. Right now the navigation view becomes gray in this case. I want to change color of navigation view dynamically, that's why I used NavigationBarModifier, but as this is not connected to this question I deleted functions that do that. Here's the current code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    var backgroundColor: Binding<Color>

    init(backgroundColor: Binding<Color>) {
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack{
            content
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    self.backgroundColor.wrappedValue
                        .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func navigationBarColor(_ bgColor: Binding<Color>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(NavigationBarModifier(backgroundColor: bgColor))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var bgColor: Color = .black
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
                  
            }  .navigationBarColor(self.$bgColor)
         
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here's how it looks now:
[image: Current state]

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of navigation bar (inline display mode for List), you can disable navigation bar to get rid of it

```
    NavigationView {

        List {
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
            }
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
            }
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
            }

        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)           // << here !!
        .navigationBarColor(self.$bgColor)

    }
```

Comment: I that possible to keep the navigationBar? As I need it for navigation :)

Comment: That is it - what you called `layer` - navigation bar - it is *a feature*. You either have it or not.